# How to share kotlin code between a project and gradle?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have an appium project written in kotlin and a build.gradle.kts. I'm using InteeliJ but also need to invoke the tests from the command line.

I have a `Datasource.kt` file which I would like to access both in the code and in gradle; right now it's just duplicated in the build.gradle.kts.

How can I effectively share the `Datasource.kt` file so that I have a single source of truth throughout the project?

Code example:

```
   if (Datasource.getValue("key").isFeatureEnabled()) {
     // check that corresponding button exists
   }
```

Gradle example:

```
tasks.test {
    ...
    useJUnitPlatform {
        if (!Datasource.hasSomeThings) {
            println("Gradle excluding \"SomeThings\" tests tag")
            excludeTags("SomeThings")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you could do that by defining a separate Gradle project (with its own `settings.gradle.kts`) for the `Datasource` stuff, and then include it both in your gradle script (with `pluginsManagement { includeBuild(...) }`) and with your project (with `includeBuild(...)`). But I'm not 100% sure of what I'm proposing, because you might need a custom pre-compiled plugin in the middle here, so maybe a Gradle guru should answer that